# Allow multiple locales as a qualification test in Mechanical Turk

Tags: mechanicalturk

I would like to have a HIT that requires users to be in the U.S. or Canada. I am using the command line tools, but it seems that any qualifications are treated as being *all* required -- I want a Boolean *or*. Is this possible?

For example, in the `.properties` file, I have:

```
# Worker_NumberHITsApproved > 100
qualification.1:00000000000000000040
qualification.comparator.1:GreaterThan
qualification.value.1:100

# Worker_PercentAssignmentsApproved > 95%
qualification.2:000000000000000000L0
qualification.comparator.2:GreaterThan
qualification.value.2:95

# Worker_Locale
qualification.3:00000000000000000071
qualification.comparator.3:EqualTo
qualification.locale.3:US
```

All three of these qualifications are required. Suppose I want to require the first two and then a locale of either `US` or `CA`. Is there syntax for this?

Comment: Could you just do it as two tasks, one requiring everything including a US locale, and the second the same except requiring a Canadian locale?

Comment: Perhaps, but I want to limit the number of times each worker does a task, so I think that wouldn't work. I'd be surprised if there wasn't a way to do this -- seems pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: this lack may have been addressed, see [dmcc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25122804/85950) for more information.

---

I think you're out of luck.  From [the API docs](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_QualificationRequirementDataStructureArticle.html) (emphasis added):

> #### The Locale Qualification
>
> ...snip...
>
> **Note**
>   A Worker must meet all of a HIT's Qualification requirements to qualify for the HIT. This means **you cannot specify more than one locale Qualification requirement**, because a given Worker will only be able to match one of the requirements. **There is no way to allow Workers of varying locales to qualify for a single HIT.**

Comment: I contacted Amazon last week about this same issue.  They said you'll just need to set up separate HITs for the US and Canada.

Comment: This is no longer the case. See @dmcc's answer.

Answer (score 6):

Mechanical Turk [now](http://mechanicalturk.typepad.com/blog/2014/07/new-qualification-comparators-add-greater-flexibility-to-qualifications-.html) supports new `In` and `NotIn` comparators which allow for multiple locales. Here's an example SOAP request from that link which requires workers from the US, Canada, or the UK:

```
<QualificationRequirement>
   <QualificationTypeId>00000000000000000071</QualificationTypeId>
   <Comparator>In</Comparator>
   <LocaleValue>US</LocaleValue>
   <LocaleValue>CA</LocaleValue>
   <LocaleValue>UK</LocaleValue>
</QualificationRequirement>
```

See also [AWS MTurk documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_QualificationRequirementDataStructureArticle.html#ApiReference_QualificationRequirementDataStructureArticle-the-locale-qualification).

Comment: Anyone know how to do this with boto? I tried this `min_qualifications.add(LocaleRequirement(comparator='In', required_to_preview=False, locale=['US', 'CA', 'GB', 'IE', 'AU']` and also this `locale='US, CA, GB, IE, AU'`. Both throw `AWS.InvalidEnumeratedParameter` which offers a list of unquoted expected values. But if I unquote, boto thinks variable.

Comment: Yes, that's entirely another matter. I've also tried with no success -- tried doing what you suggest and also subclassing `LocaleRequirement` to change its `get_as_params()` method.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25308737/1599229) explains how to do it with [mturk-python](https://github.com/ctrlcctrlv/mturk-python)

Answer (score 1):

[TurkPrime.com](https://www.turkprime.com) offers this and many more features using a web interface. You can exclude and include workers, email them, restart survey and more.

I and my colleagues have used it for a while and just love it.

Answer (score 0):

This question and its answers are fairly old at this point, but I was not able to find a solution specifically for the command line tools. I was fortunately able to figure it out after playing around for some time. In your `.properties` file:

```
# user must be located in the US or Canada
qualification.1:00000000000000000071
qualification.comparator.1:In
qualification.locale.1.1:US
qualification.locale.1.2:CA
```

A fairly modest solution but one that is not well-documented in my opinion :)