# boto and the 'In' comparator

Tags: mechanicalturk

I'm trying to use the 'In' comparator with boto for specifying multiple locales on Mechanical Turk jobs. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25122804/1599229) says it's possible, as do [the AMT docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_QualificationRequirementDataStructureArticle.html#ApiReference_QualificationRequirementDataStructureArticle-the-locale-qualification).

I tried:

```
min_qualifications.add(
    LocaleRequirement(
        comparator='In',
        required_to_preview=False,
        locale=['US', 'CA', 'GB', 'IE', 'AU']))
```

I also tried, variously:

```
locale='US, CA, GB, IE, AU'
locale='US|CA|GB|IE|AU'
locale='US CA GB IE AU'
```

How is it done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because something is possible in the mTurk API does not mean that Boto will support it. Boto has not been updated for this yet.

Here's how to do it with [mturk-python](https://github.com/ctrlcctrlv/mturk-python):

```
import mturk
m = mturk.MechanicalTurk()

question = """
<QuestionForm xmlns="http://mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com/AWSMechanicalTurkDataSchemas/2005-10-01/QuestionForm.xsd">
  <Question>
    <QuestionIdentifier>answer</QuestionIdentifier>
    <QuestionContent>
      <Text>Hello world :^)</Text>
    </QuestionContent>
    <AnswerSpecification>
      <FreeTextAnswer/>
    </AnswerSpecification>
  </Question>
</QuestionForm>
"""

qual = [
        {'QualificationTypeId' : mturk.LOCALE,
         'Comparator' : 'In',
         'LocaleValue' : [{'Country':'GB'},{'Country':'US'},{'Country':'AU'}]},
]

reward = {'Amount' : 0, 'CurrencyCode' : 'USD'}

createhit = {"Title" : "Multiple locales",
                   "Description" : "https://github.com/ctrlcctrlv/mturk-python",
                   "Keywords" : "testing, one, two, three",
                   "Reward" : reward,
                   "Question" : question,
                   "QualificationRequirement" : qual,
                   "AssignmentDurationInSeconds" : 90,
                   "LifetimeInSeconds" : (60*60*24)}

r = m.create_request('CreateHIT', createhit)
print r
print m.flattened_parameters
```

[image]